# Find the first element matching conditions with preceding-sibling

Tags: selenium, xpath

My goal is to find the text contains in the first preceding-sibling which match.

My xpath is the following one : `//*[@id='myid']/parent::td(/preceding-sibling::td/label/a)[1]`

Here I want the text of the `td/label/a` the most close of the parent of `//*[@id='myid']`.

Can you tell me if you see any mistake please? Thank you a lot.

**Update 1**

This one is working `//*[@id='myid']/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td[2]/label/a` but it is not everytime `2`, sometimes it can be `6` or whatever.

**Update 2**

*Example 1*

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <label>
                <a>text</a>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input id='myid'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tobdy>
```

*Example 2*

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <label>
                <a>text</a>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input id='myid'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tobdy>
```

*Example 3*

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <label>
                <a>text</a>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr> 
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input id='myid'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tobdy>
```

Comment: Share HTML in text format

Comment: Yes I will. I added an addtional information.

Comment: @Sers I added two examples. And I have to find a generic xpath.

Comment: Why not create the selector based on the `href` ? if you want the link

Comment: @lauda because `href` is still the same

Comment: Can you have more than one link in a `tbody`?

Comment: Yes a lot of links

Comment: Could you post your complete code as a one instead of number of examples

Comment: If you have multiple links then you need to detect a pattern in the way they are ordered and/or specific link format and/or a data input

Comment: Is your question answered or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'd need to go up to any ancestors; just go to the first preceding `td` (that contains a `label/a`)...

```xml
//input[@id='myid']/preceding::td[label/a][1]/label/a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath below. Get first parent `tr` and it's child `label/a`

```
//input[@id='myid']/ancestor::tr[1]//label/a
```

One more way is to use [union operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#node-sets) in xpath with all locators for all cases in order you need:

```
//input[@id='myid']/ancestor::td/preceding-sibling::td/label/a | //input[@id='myid']/ancestor::tr[1]/preceding-sibling::tr//label/a
```

Comment: Thank you but with this, I get two element, not one. Indeed, I want the nearest one. Moreover, sometimes, it can be in another `tr`. I added another example.

Comment: So, with xpath, it is not possible to say, "take the last element you found according to the condition"?

Comment: If you `input` element is always last, no `label` elements after it, then you can get the last one

Comment: `input` is not the last one. But I want to catch the last `label/a` preceding the `input`. I hope it is clear.

Comment: I understood that, the last solution is to use OR. Check the answer update

Comment: Thank you. But it is not possible to do something like `//input[@id='myid']/preceding::td[last()]/label/a`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208707/discussion-between-sers-and-royce).

Comment: Ok, it will return last element, but it's the same as my solution. Last label can be after input

Comment: Yes there is some label after the input. But I want the last before the input.

Comment: Minor correction: `|` is not "OR"; it's the [union operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#node-sets).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like table content are dynamic as i can see in your examples but `<tbody>` must be one for that table.

```
(//input[@id='myid']/preceding::td/label/a)[last()]
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes but not for the third one.

Comment: But it is working only if there is only one `a` correct? If there is several `label/a` all will be catched right? I need only the the last one

Comment: The last one before the input.

Comment: I seems that `(//input[@id='myid']/preceding::td/label/a)[last()]` is working...